# HttpClient doesn't retrieve header "Location" in response (while the browser request does)

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpclient, saml

I'm executing a call in the browser, then checking the contents. Chrome tells me that the response headers contain one called *Location*. When I execute call to the same URL using `HttpClient`, I get the header too but it's `null`. I don't feel confident to pass judgement on if it's me missing something or if there's a difference in how `HttpClient` instance operates compared to the operations of the browser.

First, I'm getting the cookie that allows me to identify myself at the target page.

```
string url = "https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/service/login/login"
  + "?targetPage=https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/service/overview/"
  + "&failurePage=https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/service/login/error/login-failed"
  + "&cancelPage=https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieJar };
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

HttpResponseMessage result = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
Cookie cookie = cookieJar.GetCookies(uri).First(e => e.Name == "pm_retention_urls");
```

Then, using this cookie, I'm trying to obtain a SAML query string that allows me to send an authorization request.

```
string url = "https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/service/login/discoresponse"
  + "?spId=default"
  + "&entityID=https%3A%2F%2Feid.legitimeringstjanst.se%2Fmobilt-bankid%2F";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
cookieJar.Add(cookie);
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieJar };
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = uri;

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
HttpResponseHeaders headers = response.Headers;
```

I have no certain next step how to trouble-shoot it. Googling confirms that this is the proper approach in general case. Obviously I'm doing something different compared to doing it in the browser but I can't say how to deduce what, let alone how to resolve it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be in `response.Content.Headers`?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location location is sent when there is a redirection. Trye AllowAutoRedirect = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler used by the http client is automatically redirecting by default and removes the redirect response headers from the result. Or you can say it does not forward the headers to the eventual response.
If you disable the automatic redirect you can read the location header in the response. You should take care of calling the redirect target yourself, until you get the actual result.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    CookieContainer = cookieJar,
    AllowAutoRedirect = false
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = uri;
var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
var location = response.Headers["Location"];
// Call the get operation on the location url to continue.
```

Also - some more [useful reading](https://long2know.com/2016/07/capturing-redirects-with-httpclient/).

Comment: Your answer resolved my issue - it was the *false* on *AllowAutoRedirect*. I have a follow-up, though. In my case, I have to use `response.Headers.Location` because the syntax you suggest, `response.Headers["Location"]` doesn't compile. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Oh, one more thing. You got me going but I noticed another issue. I asked it in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105194/httpclient-delivers-location-equal-to-null-at-redirection-while-corresponding-b), if you have time to glance at it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I might have been using .Net framework, because that was not clear from the tags. It does not really matter though. Getting the location with `.Location` is essentially the same.