# HttpClient delivers Location equal to null at redirection (while corresponding browser call contains URL)

Tags: c#, redirect, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core-2.2

I'm getting a cookie and using it, continue to emulate the steps that corresponding browser steps give. Since the auto-redirection is turned off, I have to execute each step individually, fetching the location in the response headers using it in the next. After three such operations, the response's headers contain location field but it's null. Carrying out the corresponding operations using the browser, contains an actual location in every redirection step.

```
private static Uri ObtainExecutor(Uri referer, Uri uri, Cookie cookie)
{
  CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
  cookieJar.Add(cookie);
  HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
  {
    CookieContainer = cookieJar,
    AllowAutoRedirect = false
  };
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = referer;
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = uri.Host;

  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
  HttpResponseHeaders headers = response.Headers;
  return new Uri(uri, response.Headers.Location);
}
```

I have no idea how to troubleshoot it further. I've compared the headers noticing nothing of relevance. I've sharked it with the same result, not being able to grasp the overload of packages coming in. Of course, I've googled it for over a week too.

I'm sure there's a tiny difference in how the call is executed but I lack ability to see it. The sample below connects to the actual server and shows the spot where the redirection location is missing. (My apologies for the large sample - I tried to make it minimal but making sure not to leave out a relevant detail unclear to me.)

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    const string url = "https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/service/login/login"
    + "?targetPage=https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/service/overview/"
    + "&failurePage=https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/service/login/error/login-failed"
    + "&cancelPage=https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/";
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    Cookie cookie = GenerateCookie(uri);
    Uri discovery = DiscoverService(cookie);
    Uri execution = ObtainExecutor(uri, discovery, cookie);
    Uri conversation = ObtainConversor(uri, execution, cookie);
  }

  private static Cookie GenerateCookie(Uri uri)
  {
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieJar };
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
    HttpContent content = response.Content;

    Cookie cookie = cookieJar.GetCookies(uri)
      .Cast<Cookie>()
      .First(e => e.Name == "pm_retention_urls");

    return cookie;
  }

  private static Uri DiscoverService(Cookie cookie)
  {
    string url = "https://www.pensionsmyndigheten.se/service/login/discoresponse"
      + "?spId=default"
      + "&entityID=https%3A%2F%2Feid.legitimeringstjanst.se%2Fmobilt-bankid%2F";
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    cookieJar.Add(cookie);
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
      CookieContainer = cookieJar,
      AllowAutoRedirect = false
    };
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = uri;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = uri.Host;

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
    HttpResponseHeaders headers = response.Headers;

    return headers.Location;
  }

  private static Uri ObtainExecutor(Uri referer, Uri uri, Cookie cookie)
  {
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    cookieJar.Add(cookie);
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
      CookieContainer = cookieJar,
      AllowAutoRedirect = false
    };
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = referer;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = uri.Host;

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
    HttpResponseHeaders headers = response.Headers;
    return new Uri(uri, response.Headers.Location);
  }

  private static Uri ObtainConversor(Uri referer, Uri uri, Cookie cookie)
  {
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    cookieJar.Add(cookie);
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
      CookieContainer = cookieJar,
      AllowAutoRedirect = false
    };
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = referer;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = uri.Host;

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
    HttpResponseHeaders headers = response.Headers;

    // Figure out why the returned redirection URL is empty.
    Uri redirection = headers.Location;
    // It should be containing the following value.
    redirection = new Uri(
      "https://idpproxy.pensionsmyndigheten.se/idp/Authn/SamlSP?conversation=e1s1");

    return redirection;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a redirect happening. If you set `AllowAutoRedirect` to true, the content of the response is the same. I just think your code is complete and you're ready to use your session cookie for requests.

Comment: @Silvermind Precisely! However, when I perform the action manually in the browser, the list of networks requests clearly produces a header with location set to something. I've turned off JS for all sites to ensure that I follow the same steps using HttpClient. What I suspect is that one of the calls differ in some detail I'm missing and hence produces a different result on one of the servers at a later stage. I'm thinking that **precisely** the same request should produce **precisely** the same result. Any hints on how to deduce such a point? I'm about to give it up.   :)

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps you can reenable the redirect and check fiddler or something like that to see what's happening.